# Two Dimensional Array - arr[i][0] Gives Wrong Result - JavaScript ASP.NET C#

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, razor, razor-pages

I have an Array of Arrays populated from C# Model:

```
var AllObjectsArray = [];
        @foreach(var Cobject in Model.ObjectList) 
        {
            @:AllObjectsArray.push(new Array("@Cobject.Name", "@Cobject.Value", "@Cobject.Keyword"));
        }

var SelectedObjects = [];
        uniqueobj.forEach(function (element) {

            SelectedObjects.push(new Array(AllObjectsArray.filter(elem => elem[0] === element))); //makes array of selected objects with their values(name,value,keyword)
        });
```

I am trying to get second parameter of each and every inner Array and add it to new array containing those elements like this:

```
var ValuesArray = [];
        for (i = 0; i < SelectedObjects.length; i++) {
            ValuesArray.push(SelectedObjects[i][0]) //problem here i think
        };
```

Unfortunately, on:

```
alert(ValuesArray + " : " + SelectedObjects);
```

I get nothing for `ValuesArray`. The other data for `SelectedObjects` loads properly with all three parameters correctly returned for each and every inner Array,so it is not empty. I must be iterating wrongly.

EDIT:
SOme more info as I am not getting understood what I need.

Lets say SelectedObjects[] contains two records like this:

```
{ name1, number1, keyword1}
{ name2, number2, keyword2}
```

Now, what I need is to populate `ValuesArray` with `nane1` and `name2`.
That is why I was guessing I should iterate over `SelectedObjects` and get `SelectedObject[i][0]` where in my guessing `i` stands for inner array index and `1` stands for number part of that inner array. Please correct me and put me in the right direction as I am guesing from C# way of coding how to wrap my head around js.

However SelectedObject[i][0] gives me all SelectedObject with all three properties(name, value and keyword) and I should get only name's part of the inner Array.

What is happening here?

Hope I explained myself better this time.

EDIT:

I think I know why it happens, since SelectedObjects[i][0] returns whole inner Array and SelectedObjects[i][1] gives null, it must mean that SelectedObjects is not Array of Arrays but Array of strings concatenated with commas.

Is there a way to workaround this? SHould I create array of arrays ddifferently or maybe split inner object on commas and iteratee through returned strings?

Comment: Did you find any error in browser console?

Comment: uniqueobj is basically an array that contains first Array of Arrays object that match user's selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, SelectedObjects[i][1] should rather be SelectedObjects[i][0].
But as far as I understand you want something like

```
var ValuesArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < SelectedObjects.length; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j <SelectedObjects[i].length; j++) {
         ValuesArray.push(SelectedObjects[i][j]);
    }
};
```

Comment: I put [i][[1] because I am trying to get inside of array[i] and get its [1] value instead of whole object. I am coming from c# and am totally new to us syntax

Comment: yout solution will get me all parameters fro every inner array, right? I don't need all "j" values, just the "j=1"

Comment: That was it, to access second property I had to write SelectedObjects[i][j][1]. Thank you Piotr

Answer (score 0):

In this snippet

```
var ValuesArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < SelectedObjects.length; i++) {
   ValuesArray.push(SelectedObjects[i][1]) //problem here i think
};
```

You're pointing directly at the **second** item in SelectedObjects[i]

Maybe you want the first index, 0

Comment: that's what I want, but instead of getting that value, I get nothing 4 times separated by commas, like: ,,, instead of 5,4,3,5

Comment: and if I put 0 instead of 1 I get whole [i] object with [i][0], [i][1] and [i][2]. I don't want that and I cannot understand why [i][1] results in nothing

Comment: I think maybe you're rendering into the arrays badly. You're actually 3 levels of array deep, your reference may need to look like [i][0][0] or something

Comment: yes, i think so too. I am trying to do so but no luck

Comment: @differerntDure please look at my edit, I think the SelectedObjects is not array of arrays but one dimensional array. This would explain why SelectedObjects[i][0] returns full inner array and SelectedObjects[i][1] returns nothing, as what I thought is an inner array, it is simply one object that is formed by three elements separated by comma.